# portfolio project using reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react. I was creating a portfolio project from a guide on youtube (react portfolio by adibaba) but I am stuck. When I run the code in my browser after coding the following code it displays nothing! help me track the error
/this is profile.js file/

```
import React from 'react';

function Profile(props) {
    return (
        <div className='profile-container'>
            <div className='profile-parent'>
                <div className='profile-details'>
                    <div className='colz'>
                        <a href='#'>
                         < i className='fa fa-facebook-square'></i>  
                        </a>
                        <a href='#'>
                         < i className='fa fa-google-plus-square'></i>  
                        </a>
                        <a href='#'>
                         < i className='fa fa-instagram'></i>  
                        </a>
                        <a href='#'>
                         < i className='fa fa-youtube-squire'></i>  
                        </a>
                        <a href='#'>
                         < i className='fa fa-twitter'></i>  
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Profile;

/and this is app.js file/

import profile from './portfolioContainer/Home/Profile'
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <profile/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Capitalize Profile in your app.js file (import and in the render)

Comment: And check your logs; you should be getting a warning.

Comment: Hi, can you try to import profile with capital letter. 
`import Profile from './portfolioContainer/Home/Profile'`

Comment: I have capitalized profile in my app.js and am getting a warning;  Line 1:8:  'Profile' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars